# Differential equation $f'(x)=10f(x)-5$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having some trouble with solving the following differential equation:
\begin{equation}
f'(x)=10f(x)-5
\end{equation}
I keep coming back to the solution
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{1}{10}(e^{x+c}+5)
\end{equation}
But I think I am forgetting to do something.

Comment: Yes, you forgot something. What is the solution of $f'(x)=10f(x)$ ? Moreover, differentiating your result would show that it does not satisfy the equation. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{l}
\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} = 10y - 5\\
\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} = 10(y - \frac{1}{2})\\
\frac{{dy}}{{y - \frac{1}{2}}} = 10dx\\
\ln (y - \frac{1}{2}) = 10x + \ln (C)\\
y - \frac{1}{2} = {e^{10x + \ln (C)}}\\
y = C{e^{10x}} + \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}$$

Comment: $$\int \frac{dy}{2y - 1} = \frac{1}{2} \ln(2y - 1) = 5x + C_1 \implies \ln(2y - 1) = 10x + C_2$$

Comment: @Mattos: Thank you very much. Right factorization at the beginning will save life.

Comment: @friedmanfanboy: Did calculations a little shorter. Thank you.